# Problem with Installing intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.2-0intel3_i386.deb

Tags: apt

I have *Ubuntu 13.10* installed.

When I try to install `intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.2-0intel3_i386.deb`

I have error:

```
dependency is not satisfiable libpackagekit-glib2-14
```

Why this happens ?

Comment: Try this in terminal `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: Intel has released new graphics drivers for Linux on its official page. Check out [Intel(R) Graphics Installer 1.0.6 for Linux](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads) section. It works for Ubuntu 13.10 too.

Comment: Without the lines that are previous to that one, is impossible to say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

If Mitch's solution doesn't solve the issue, try:

```
sudo apt-get remove libpackagekit-glib2-14
wget https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/13.04/main/pool/13.04/i/intel-linux-graphics-installer/intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.2-0intel3_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i intel-linux-graphics*.deb && sudo apt-get install –f
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

(To reinstall the removed library; if the error still exists:)

```
sudo apt-get install libpackagekit-glib2-14
```

Comment: E: Unable to locate package intel-linux-graphics-installer

Comment: <edited the post>

Comment: I still can't install :/

Comment: http://i39.tinypic.com/25iugoz.png

Comment: The error persists when I try to install the package. Attempting to install libpackagekit-glib2-14 returns the message:

This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look in the package repo:
http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=+libpackagekit-glib2&searchon=names
...you'll see that 13.10 (saucy) only has a `-16` build of `libpackagekit-glib2` and the intel installer wants a `-14' build.

I'd assume that if you were on raring it would all work fine. You can verify that your system has the `-16` build using:

```
dpkg -s libpackagekit-glib2-16
```

...and looking at the second line:

```
Status: install ok installed
```

Apparently there'll be a new version that'll support us: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/comment/431#comment-431